# Static linking problem with zeromq in Rust

Tags: rust, zeromq

I try to statically link my zeromq application but totally failing on this task.

Here my environment narrowed down to the core problem.

```bash
docker container run -it --rm rust:1.71.0

cargo init foo
cd foo
cargo add zmq-sys
echo "fn main() { unsafe { zmq_sys::zmq_ctx_new() }; }" > src/main.rs
```

And when I run (btw: I'm on a linux x86_64 machine) this:

```bash
RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

I get this error:

```
   ...
   Compiling version-compare v0.1.1
   Compiling zeromq-src v0.2.5+4.3.4
   Compiling toml v0.7.6
   Compiling system-deps v6.1.1
   Compiling zmq-sys v0.12.0
   Compiling foo v0.1.0 (/foo)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/usr/local/cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" VSLANG="1033" "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustc96qgBc/symbols.o" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/foo-cb6ba11158d315c4.foo.b2f903485695e401-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/foo-cb6ba11158d315c4.foo.b2f903485695e401-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/foo-cb6ba11158d315c4.foo.b2f903485695e401-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/foo-cb6ba11158d315c4.38dmy2d9chj96ssl.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps" "-L" "/foo/target/release/deps" "-L" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/build/zmq-sys-189974278a500c32/out/lib" "-L" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/build/zmq-sys-189974278a500c32/out/lib" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libzmq_sys-fc6815d34ec73a41.rlib" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblibc-25ef17eb55ea3a7e.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-0d91c78a7710ed2e.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-9bfeb974ba4dc4e7.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-7dd2d47ddb5fff81.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-18d5ce8e8a320b85.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-69d2770595dc6161.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-b156a020cc470e38.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-84091f15e468b1ee.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-fbde6acb28b510ca.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-e9de5d8ee4e7a3dd.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-9023252e4f119830.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-fcbb01769e88af40.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-f69e84994e245fea.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-27b55c02caca49ea.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-579b26075cbe9eca.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-54c30397d4b33d3b.rlib" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-lgcc_eh" "-lgcc" "-lc" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-65fb576691133eee.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-3fff6412017c0b89.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-fd3918c72578db43.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-2a597573799b576f.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lstdc++" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/foo-cb6ba11158d315c4" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-static-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-0d91c78a7710ed2e.rlib(std-0d91c78a7710ed2e.std.a2d7a4c8dd6a1366-cgu.0.rcgu.o): in function `std::sys::unix::os::home_dir::fallback':
          /rustc/8ede3aae28fe6e4d52b38157d7bfe0d3bceef225/library/std/src/sys/unix/os.rs:642: warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
          /usr/bin/ld: /foo/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libzmq_sys-fc6815d34ec73a41.rlib(711a6e249c8746d4-ip_resolver.o): in function `zmq::ip_resolver_t::do_getaddrinfo(char const*, char const*, addrinfo const*, addrinfo**) [clone .localalias]':
          ip_resolver.cpp:(.text._ZN3zmq13ip_resolver_t14do_getaddrinfoEPKcS2_PK8addrinfoPPS3_+0xd): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
          /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.71.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-0d91c78a7710ed2e.rlib(std-0d91c78a7710ed2e.std.a2d7a4c8dd6a1366-cgu.0.rcgu.o): undefined reference to symbol '__tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3'
          /usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

  = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

error: could not compile `foo` (bin "foo") due to previous error
```

Can someone help me out how to make static linking work?

Comment: The `zmq-sys` crate interfaces with an external library (`libzmq`). You will need to install the static version of `libzmq` if you want to link with it.

Comment: But why does it then work without static linking if requires the external library? As far as I undertand, the `libzmq` is not longer required to be installed, because it is compiled from source via a the crate zeromq-src

Comment: I don't know why but when doing this with the alpine image and the musl target it works then: `docker container run -it --rm rust:1.71-alpine`